# Rest Assured how ignore a parameter in the api respond and compare it with a json

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Hello i am using rest assured to compare a expected json but the problem that i have right now it the ID parameter is different every time i am executing the call from rest assured and i want to find the adequate way to validate the response ignoring the id parameter in the response below the code i am using

```
            body("", equalTo(expectedJson.get())).
            extract().response();
```

in the expected json has an id that the next time that i execute the call will change so the test will fail.

My expected json

{
"success": false,
"Description": "This is a test",
"Id": 6,
}

Answer (score 0):

You can validate all another values and don't touch `id` (or at least checking it for not null) by using following code:

```
response
      .then()
      .assertThat()
      .statusCode(200)
      .body("success", equalTo("yourValue2"))
      .body("Description", equalTo("yourValue2"))
      .body("id", notNullValue());
```